# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatapplication/com.example.chatapplication.MainActivity}:

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I was creating a messaging app the Haxm was not downloaded
when I Downloaded from a Github link the flamingo software started to crash
then I deleted the Haxm and tried to run in my phone but launch was successful but app is not opening it says there is a bug Iam new to android studio and I don't know where to look for bugs in my code because my debugger was clean when I saw my logcat  it showed the following error
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatapplication/com.example.chatapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

```kotlin
package com.example.chatapplication

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText



private lateinit var editemail:EditText
private lateinit var editpassword:EditText
private lateinit var btn:Button
private lateinit var btn2:Button





class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editemail=findViewById(R.id.email)
        editpassword=findViewById(R.id.password)
        btn=findViewById(R.id.button)
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.button2)
        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent=Intent(this,Signup::class.java) //signup activity is empty xml and java file
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="497dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fill"
        android:text="signup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="424dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="161dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="224dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fill"
        android:text="Signin" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the entire stack trace, not just the exception line.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript is not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language) and  not even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java

Comment: Can you share your `AndroidManifest.xml `?